# Null Pointer exception in LayoutInflater in Custom Listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, baseadapter

I am beginner in android. I got NullPointerEcxeption error.

i want my activity get me listview and each listview contains image , it;s title, and it's description, 
i read article [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767227/null-pointer-exception-in-layoutinflator)

i cant get proper understand what is happen to context in MainActivity.java LayoutInflater...

I used Base Adapter instead of ArrayAdapter.

Please Help.. Thanks in advance.

Here i put some code...

one imageview, two textviews 
CustomeList.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Descript1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Title1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml , which contains the Listview..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
  </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.customadapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lv;
//Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new myAdapter(this));
    //lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}

class SingleRow {
   String title;
   String desc;
   int image;
   SingleRow(String title, String desc, int img){
    this.title=title;
    this.desc=desc;
    this.image=img;
}
}

class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 Context context;
 ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
 myAdapter(Context c){

    list=new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
    /*
     * 1. get the title, descrp, image from xml
     * 2. group each title, its related description and its image into a single row     

object.
     * 3. put single row object into array list.
     * 
     * */
    Resources res=c.getResources();

    String[] title=res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    String[] desc=res.getStringArray(R.array.desc);

    int[] img=  

 {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5};

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        list.add(new SingleRow(title[i],desc[i],img[i]));
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /*
     1. get the root view
     2. use the root view for find other view
     3. set the view.
     */

    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) 

    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list,null);

    TextView title= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    TextView desc=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ImageView img=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    SingleRow temp=list.get(position);
    title.setText(temp.title);
    desc.setText(temp.desc);
    img.setImageResource(temp.image);

    return null;
}
}
```

Error::

```
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.example.customadapter.myAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:108)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-30 18:34:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 18:39:29.697: I/Process(627): Sending signal. PID: 627 SIG: 9
```

Comment: did you define all those classes in your `Activity` java file? This is a very bad idea. I posted a sample implementation of a proper custom `ListView` with images and text, you can take a look at this to get started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469073/how-do-you-efficiently-load-bitmaps-from-drawable-folder-into-a-listview/19469076#19469076

Comment: Thank you so much Droidman. i have one confusion about ArrayAdaper and BaseAdapter. Will you give me proper doc or link ? i seen so many things but i got confused...which one is better  ..?

Comment: they are for different purposes. Simply speaking: the `BaseAdapter` is the one to use if you have a more complex custom `ListView`or `GridView` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

context variable is referenced as null

in your constructor you didnt use the parameter Context c

add this line of code

```
context=c;
```

and you are using the context inside the `getView()` method which causes the null pointer too.

in your custom adapter, `getView()` is returning `null` that triggers the null pointer exception. you need to return the inflated `view`;

replace

```
return null;
```

with

```
return row;
```

Comment: you could also suggest him to improve hit getView method applying the ViewHolder pattern and avoiding to inflated a new view every time getView is called,

Comment: yes @blackbelt , and to avoid also calling indViewById() on your resource everytime. it would make the list more efficient.

Comment: on your constructor you are not setting the context to c. i think you missed this part context=c; check your variables. the context variable is causing the null pointer because you are using it inside the getView() method

Comment: oops, i forgot..thanks, error gone..thanks user3818605,,

Comment: i will be editing my answer so you could accept it as it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used the 'context' value properly. That's the error you are getting. Also return the view.
The below code would help you. You could use the ViewHolder pattern also which would improve code efficiency.

public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;


public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListData> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myList.size();
}

@Override
public ListData getItem(int position) {
    return myList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ListData currentListData = getItem(position);

    mViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(currentListData.getTitle());
    mViewHolder.tvDesc.setText(currentListData.getDescription());
    mViewHolder.ivIcon.setImageResource(currentListData.getImgResId());

    return convertView;
}

private class MyViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle, tvDesc;
    ImageView ivIcon;

    public MyViewHolder(View item) {
        tvTitle = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvDesc = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
        ivIcon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
    }
}
```